# Google Cloud Print integration without webview

Tags: java, android, printing, google-cloud-print

I use [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android) tutorial to integrate my android application with Google Cloud Printer. It works fine, but I want do this without **WebView**.

I want to print with two steps:

1. Generate **pdf** file
2. Click button "**Print**" and submit print job

I shared my printer to anyone with link and want to print all pdf files from my application to my shared printer.

Can you share some code or tutorial?

Sorry for my english

Comment: if you downvote, please, add comment why. I search solution but nothing found, that can helps me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/java-printing-facade/source/browse/trunk/printing-facade-googlecloud/src/main/java/dk/apaq/printing/googlecloud/GoogleCloudPrintPlugin.java?r=65) link and it helps me

**ADD:**

```java
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String user = "user@gmail.com";
        String pass = "password";
        String source = "Cloud%20Printing%20Test";

        HttpGet authGet = new HttpGet(
                "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email="
                        + user
                        + "&Passwd="
                        + pass
                        + "&service=cloudprint&source=" + source);

        HttpResponse httpResponse;

        httpResponse = httpclient.execute(authGet);

        String authResponse = EntityUtils
                .toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        String authKey = authResponse.substring(authResponse
                .indexOf("Auth=") + 5);
        authKey = authKey.replace("\n", "");

        MyLog.d(TAG, "Auth key: " + authKey);

        HttpPost printPost = new HttpPost(
                "https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit?output=json");
        printPost.setHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + authKey);
        printPost.setHeader("X-CloudPrint-Proxy", source);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("printerid", "ID"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", "TEST"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("capabilities", "{capabilities=[]}"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", "123"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contentType", "text/plain"));
        printPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse printResponse = httpclient.execute(printPost);
        String lol = EntityUtils.toString(printResponse.getEntity());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But now I can print only text. If i found solution how to print pdf - I'll post code here

**ADD2:**

This code send pdf files to print

```java
File file = new File("file.pdf");
FileBody fb = new FileBody(file);
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addTextBody("printerid", "ID");
builder.addTextBody("title", "TEST2");
builder.addTextBody("capabilities", "{capabilities=[]}");
builder.addTextBody("contentType", "application/pdf");
builder.addPart("content", fb);
printPost.setEntity(builder.build());
```